# base64. Ending is not basically

Tags: base64

I thought, I know the base64 encoding, but I often see so encoded text: `iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAXwAAAG4C ... YPQr/w8B0CBr+DAkGQAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==`. I got mean, It overs by double `=`. Why does it push second void byte, if 8 bits enough satisfy empty bits of encoded text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found. Length of base64-encoded data should be divisible by 4. The remainder of division length by 4 is filled by `=`-chars. That's because conflict of bit rate. In modern systems it's used 8-bits bytes, but in base64 is used 6-bits chars. So the lowest common multiple is 24 bits or 3 bytes or 4 base64-chars. A lack is filled by `=`.